# BATCH - can't return proper value in a variable from a function

Tags: batch-file, variables, windows-7

I have read a lot of examples and questions about returning values from batch functions using variables but I can't force Windows 7 x64 cmd.exe to do it for me. ;-)

I have already tried a lot of code examples but nothing has worked as I expected. I have written a short batch program to find out how to do it, but it also hasn't worked as I expected. I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set x=10
echo x(1) = !x!
call :TestFunc !x!
echo x(2) = !x!
EndLocal
exit /b

:TestFunc
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=%~1
echo a(1) = !a!
set /a a=a+101
echo a(2) = !a!
set %~1=!a!
echo   %%~1 = %~1
echo ^^!%%~1^^! = !%~1!
EndLocal
exit /b
```

I expected that `set %1=!a!` will set the only variable being returned by the `:TestFunc`. But the result is:

```
>test_variables.bat
x(1) = 10
a(1) = 10
a(2) = 111
  %~1 = 10
!%~1! = 111
x(2) = 10
```

The most surprising for me was that there are two variables `%~1` inside the body of the `:TestFunc` - one is set locally and the other one, passed to the function and maybe also returned by the function, but not changed inside the function's body.

**Edit**

And finally, thanks to @Stephan, my exaple that is working:

```
@echo off
rem echo on
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "x=10"
set "y=x"
echo x(1) = !x!
echo y(1) = !y!
call :TestFunc !y! !x!
echo ---------------------------------
echo x(2) = !x!
echo y(2) = !y!
EndLocal
exit /b

:TestFunc
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=%~2
echo a(1) = !a!
set /a a=!a!+101
echo a(2) = !a!
EndLocal & set "%~1=%a%"
exit /b
```

and the result:

```
>test_variables.bat
x(1) = 10
y(1) = x
a(1) = 10
a(2) = 111
---------------------------------
x(2) = 111
y(2) = x
```

There were two tricks to do:

1. Put the first variable name (x) into the other variable (y) value and call the function with both variable names as parameters
2. @Stephan's trick with setting returned variable value after the `EndLocal` clause (`EndLocal & set "%~1=%a%"`).

Comment: Due to using setlocal/endlocal ***nothing*** is returned from `:TestFunc` - The other aspect is answered by Stephan

Comment: I missed the `setlocal/endlocal`thing. Answer adapted. (thanks, @LotPings)

Answer (score 4):

`set %~1=!a!` sets  a variable named by the value of `%~1` (which is `10` in your example). so the command is parsed as: `set 10=111`

(you shouldn't use variablenames starting with a digit)

What I think you want to do is:

```
echo on
set "var=xxx"
call :sub var 10
echo %var%
goto :eof

:sub
setlocal
set /a tmpvar=%~2+55
endlocal & set "%~1=%tmpvar%"
```

I left `echo on` to see exactly, how the parser "translates" your code.

The main trick is for the variable to survive an `endlocal`. This is achieved by tricking the parser with the line `endlocal & set "%~1=%tmpvar%`; `%tmpvar%` is actually evaluated *before* `endlocal` takes effect.

Comment: Variablenames starting with a digit are not a good idea. Neither is using `tmp`, `temp`, `date`, `time`, `random` `username` or `errorlevel` amongst others as they are system-defined. Safe within a startlocal/endlocal bracket, but not in general. They are very tempting names, but if you use them you'll likely encounter unexpected problems.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan for your explanation and **the main trick**. It helped me a lot to make my batch working - not exactly as I expected but returning vales. ;-) It's still looking strange for me and I still don't see everything clear. In my example it didn't work until I set my first **variable name** to the secondary variable value.
```set "x=10"
set "y=x"```

Comment: @Magoo, I didn't named any variable starting with a digit or I didn't do that intentionally. ;-) What I wanted to do was to pass value (10) in the variable (x) as a parameter to the function, then read the value from the variable passed to the function, change it somehow and return changed value to the main procedure. That's why it didn't work - because probably my **value** was treated as a variable name.

Comment: @McVik : As Stephan explained, setting `%~1` actually set a variable named `10` since `%~1` had the value `10`. Since you were using `delayedexpansion`, batch duly reported that `!%~1!` was the *value* (111) that you'd assigned to the *variable* `10`. Fact is, batch actually doesn't have "functions" in the manner that other languages assign the *result* of a function to some variable. Batch only has *procedures* which can be constructed to imitate functions. And lots of loose terminology where people use familiar terms without appending a war-and-peace disclaimer to every post.

Comment: Thank you @Magoo for your explanation. Now it's clear for me. :-)