# BATCH - function called in a for-loop doesn't return value

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, variables, windows-7

I needed to complicate a little [my batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842646/batch-cant-return-proper-value-in-a-variable-from-a-function) and it again doesn't work. I need to call my function (which is getting some value in a variable, changing it and returning changed value as a result) s-times in a loop `for /L %%n in (1,1,%s%) do call :TestFunc`.

In this example I want to call a function that adds value of 101 to the value received in function call parameter, return the result to the main procedure and I want to repeat that 5 times in a for-loop putting given result in the parameter of the next function call.

While my batch has been working well without a loop, it broke up after putting function call in a loop like this:

```
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "s=5"
set "x=10"
set "y=x"
echo before
echo x = !x!
echo y = !y!
for /L %%n in (1,1,!s!) do (
    call :TestFunc %%n !y! !x!
    echo after
    echo x.2 = !x!, y.2 = !y!
    timeout /t 120
  )
EndLocal
exit /b

:TestFunc
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set a=%~3
set m=%~1
echo inside
echo a = !a!, m = !m!
set /a a=!a!+101
EndLocal & set "%~2=!a!"
goto :eof
```

And a result is:

```
>test_variables.bat
before
x = 10
y = x
inside
a = 10, m = 1
after
x.2 = , y.2 = x

waiting 120 s, press any key to continue...
inside
a = , m = 2
after
x.2 = , y.2 = x
...
```

I expected that the value of `x` will change to 111, 212, 313, 414 and 515. But as you can see, the value of `x` (x.2) is "**nothing**" after leaving the function `:TestFunc` and coming back to the main procedure (inside the loop). So the next function call in the loop transfers "nothing" to the function in the function call parameter and nothing appears in the variable `a` inside the function body over and over again.

While calling the function without the loop, the value of the `x` variable after leaving the function was 111, as it was expected. An example of that working code was put in the "edited" part of [my post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842646/batch-cant-return-proper-value-in-a-variable-from-a-function).

I know that I can bypass this problem avoiding using a function call and putting its body code inside the for-loop but this is only a test example. In my final batch program which is much more complicated I need to call my function more then one time, from different blocks of code.

Comment: I may have missed something in my understanding of what you are trying to achieve, but I see no reason whatsoever in using `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` or `EndLocal & ` inside `:TestFunc`.

Comment: Why do you enable delayed expansion in the sub-routine? you actually do not need it...

Comment: Of course I don't need ```EnableDelayedExpansion``` in my exaple :-) but I do need it in my final batch program, so I want to write and test a simple example with ```DelayedExpansion``` enabled to be sure that it will work also in my target batch program.

Comment: @McVik, can you please explain why you need it then, because you enabled it at the start of the script and ended it at the end, so it seems to me as if it's enabled all of the time.

Comment: @Compo, that's because I do lots of operations based on current system time and other time values stored in variables, using some loops and procedures. When I didn't use ```EnableDelayedEspansion```, it didn't work at all.

Comment: @McVic, you did use it, as long as you don't end that delayed expansion, it will remain in place for the entire script. Just remove the two pieces of information I advised you to remove in my opening comment, and try the script again. If you want help for code not in your actual question, you'll need to post that code as part of a new question, because it is clear that you're unsure how delayed expansion actually works.

Comment: Thank you @Compo for your care and your advice. My only problem with my code at this moment was solved by @wasatchwizard, and - regarding to your comments - it was connected with ```DelayedExpansion``` or rather with notation used while ```DelayedExpansion``` is enabled / disabled. When I saw this, it was absolutely clear for me. Now my script works pretty well just as I expected, so everything is ok. My exaple was very good ;-) because it displayed where can be a trap with notation, what was one of the main reasons to put those ```EnableDelayedExpansion```  clauses there. ;-) Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The second-to-last line in `TestFunc` should look like this:

```
EndLocal & set "%~2=%a%"
```

The explanation is that you are no longer in the delayed expansion block and so `!a!` no longer exists.. so you use the regular `%a%` to get its final value..

Comment: Oh, blind me! stupid me! :-) Of course! Thank you very much @wasatchwizard.